# Fail to install Alfresco due to DB connection error

Tags: postgresql, alfresco, alfresco-share

I had installed Alfresco community edition on and it was running fine. Suddenly I started getting database connection error. Only difference I see is IP address has changed. I could not find out where I had to modify IP address, so I decided to install it from scratch. But while installing I got the below error.

[image]

Below are the entries in pg_hba.conf

## IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

## IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Comment: And the error is for missing entry for IP 192.168.1.116

Comment: As I know Alfresco automatically makes this entries during installation because as part of Alfresco installation postgresql is installed.

Comment: And obviously this time it didn't.

Comment: yes. do I need to manually make entry? I didn't find way to manually do it. because once i get this error then whole Alfresco installation stops and if I do fresh installation then it takes new directory path

Comment: A possible workaround: install Postgres first, then take the "Advanced" route during the Alfresco installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been throgh same error

You need to add this entry in your pg_hba.conf file

host    all         all         xxx.xx.xx.xx/24     trust

where xxx.xx.xx.xx is your ip.